# Allow vertical scrolling of outer ScrollViewer inside inner horizontal-scrolling ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

When you have a ScrollViewer within a ScrollViewer, scrolling with the scroll wheel is limited to the inner one. That makes sense when they have the same "orientation". But when the outer allows only vertical scrolling, and the inner allows only horizontal scrolling, I'd expect scrolling with the mouse wheel inside the inner one to scroll vertically in the outer ScrollViewer. It doesn't. Is there a way to get it to do this?

In the following code, try using the scroll wheel while inside the red letter area:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</TextBlock>

        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel >
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccccccccccc dddddddddddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee fffffffffffffffff ggggggggggggggggggggggg</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccccccccccc dddddddddddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee fffffffffffffffff ggggggggggggggggggggggg</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccccccccccc dddddddddddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee fffffffffffffffff ggggggggggggggggggggggg</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccccccccccc dddddddddddddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee fffffffffffffffff ggggggggggggggggggggggg</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with using code-behind, you can create an event handler for the `PreviewMouseWheel` event of the "child" `ScollViewer`, and within the event handler, you can pass the `MouseWheelEventArgs` information to the "parent" `ScrollViewer` to raise its own `MouseWheel` event.

First, there will be a couple of minor changes to the XAML:

Give the "parent" `ScrollViewer` a name so it can be referenced from code-behind:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="parentScrollViewer"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

Create an event handler for the `PreviewMouseWheel` event of the "child" `ScrollViewer`:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel">
```

Finally, implement the code in the event handler to raise the "parent" `MouseWheel` event:

```
private void ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var mouseWheelEventArgs = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);
    mouseWheelEventArgs.RoutedEvent = ScrollViewer.MouseWheelEvent;
    mouseWheelEventArgs.Source = sender;
    this.parentScrollViewer.RaiseEvent(mouseWheelEventArgs);
}
```