# How do I enable horizontal scroll and disable vertical scroll within a scrollviewer in UWP?

Tags: uwp-xaml

Here's the XAML with which I'm starting:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="500"
              Width="500"
              Name="parentScrollViewer">
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid Height="300"
                  Background="Red" />

            <ScrollViewer Width="500"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          Name="childScrollViewer">
                <Grid Height="300"
                      Width="600"
                      Background="Green"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <Grid Height="300"
                  Background="Blue" />        
        </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Basically, if I disable all scrolling on the childScrollViewer, I get the vertical effect I want (parentScrollViewer can scroll through everything), but if I enable horizontal scrolling on the childScrollViewer (to get the right horizontal effect), I loose the vertical effect I want.

I don't REALLY care if I have to make everyone use the scrollbar in order to scroll horizontally, but it would be a bonus if I did not have to do that.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56211199/allow-vertical-scrolling-of-outer-scrollviewer-inside-inner-horizontal-scrolling) post, which seemed to be what I was looking for, but I couldn't figure out the UWP equivalent (perhaps redirecting PointerWheelChanged event to parentScrollViewer?)

Alternately, I looked into making horizontal scrolling enabled if and only if the scrollbar was touched (or mouse pressed), but I could not find the right event for which to listen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that I feel pretty good about, but I'm not going to mark it (at least for a while) in hopes that someone has a better solution.

I just added a scrollviewer with just enough height to display the scrollbar and made the childScrollViewer enabled whenever it is touched.

Here's my XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="500"
                  Width="500"
                  Name="parentScrollViewer">
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid Height="300"
                  Background="Red" />
            <ScrollViewer Width="500"
                          HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                          Name="childScrollViewer"
                          PointerPressed="ChildScrollViewer_PointerPressed"
                          PointerReleased="ChildScrollViewer_PointerReleased"
                          PointerExited="ChildScrollViewer_PointerReleased"
                          >

                <Grid Height="300"
                      Width="600"
                      Background="Green">
                    <TextBlock Text="left"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBlock Text="right"
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Right" />

                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <ScrollViewer Width="500"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          Name="childScrollViewer2"
                          ViewChanged="ScrollViewer_ViewChanged">

                <Grid Height="16"
                      Width="600"
                      Background="Green">

                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <Grid Height="300"
                  Background="Blue" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

And here's my c#:

```
        private void ChildScrollViewer_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            childScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
        }

        private void ChildScrollViewer_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            childScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
        }

        private void ScrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(sender is ScrollViewer s))
            {
                return;
            }
            childScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
            childScrollViewer.ChangeView(s.HorizontalOffset, null, null);
            childScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
        }
```